# How to initialize hook with data that can only be accessed after mounting?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, react-hooks

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import { useCollection } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";
import { db } from "@/firebase/clientApp";
import { collection } from "firebase/firestore";

export default function Test(){
    const router = useRouter();
    const {id} = router.query
    const [data, dataLoading, dataError] = useCollection(collection(db, "drafts", id), {})

    return(
    <div>Hello!</div>
    )
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the value of id for the initialization of the useCollection hook. However, id changes, and is first undefined, then changes to the correct value. This makes the whole thing break, and the above isn't even valid in typescript. I need to initialize the useCollection hook after id is defined, which is only after the component "mounts". I tried placing the useCollection(...) in a useEffect, but it does not work.

Comment: What's the TypeScript error you are getting? And are you getting any runtime errors? If so, is it in that `dataError`, or is the component breaking the entire app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using nextjs you can get advantage of `getServerSideProps` to generate the id for your component as initial props so it will be always defined :

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  const id = params.id;

  return {
    props: {
      id,
    },
  };
}
```

and you recieve it as props from your component :

```js
export default function Test({id}){
 //...
}
```